# Definitions for Azure Eventhubs metric

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

Can anyone be kind enough to give a brief decription as to what these metrics value mean:
`-incoming (Messages)
-successful (Requests)
-failed (Requests)
-failed.internalservererror (Requests)
-failed.serverbusy (Requests)
-failed.other (Requests)
-outgoing (Messages)
-throughput (bytes)`

Incoming messages would be the events I am capturing but what are the failed request and successful request? Are outgoing messages, the messages consumed by my consumer?